# multiple selector on change, which was selected?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a jquery code like this

```
$('.select1, .select2, .select3').on('change',function(){

        var select1 = $(this).val();
        var select2 = $(this).val();
        var select3 = $(this).val();
});
```

How do i determine which `<select>` class was changed, so i could put an if-else. Something like this

```
$('.select1, .select2, .select3').on('change',function(){
    
            if (selected == '.select1') {
                       var select1 = $(this).val();
                       var select2 = select3 = 'bla';
             }
            else if (selected == '.select2') {
             var select2 = $(this).val();
             var select1 = select3 = 'bla';
            }
            else {
               var select3 = $(this).val();
               var select1 = select2 = 'bla';
            }
    });
```

Thanks

Comment: inside the listener, `this` will be the changed select

Comment: Use `var select = $(this).val();` instead

Comment: What do you need to do with the values? There might be a very simple approach if that is known

Comment: @charlietfl its for a chain select of 7. if the 2nd select is selected. get value for 1st and 2nd select, and empty the rest. so in my ajax post i can set empty to the rest `data:{ select1: select1, select2: select2, select3: select3, select4:select4 ....},`

Comment: If you store the collection you can get the index of the one selected within the collection if that helps `var $sels = $('.select1, .select2, .select3').on('change',function(){ console.log($sels.index(this);})`. Then loop through the collection and if index is greater than current do what you need to. Still a bit unclear what you actually need

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try using jQuery's `.hasClass()` to check the class of the current select element.

**Demo:**

```js
$('.select1, .select2, .select3').on('change',function(){
    var v;
    if ($(this).hasClass('.select1')) {
      var select1 = 'bla';
      v = $(this).val();
    }
    else if ($(this).hasClass('.select2')){
      var select2 = 'blabla';
      v = $(this).val();
    }
    else {
      var select3 = 'hi';
      v = $(this).val();
    }
    console.log(v);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select class="select1">
  <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
  <option value="saab">Saab</option>
</select>
<select class="select2">
  <option value="mango">Mango</option>
  <option value="banana">Banana</option>
</select>
<select class="select3">
  <option value="mobile">Mobile</option>
  <option value="laptop">Laptop</option>
</select>
```

Comment: i get false when i `alert($(this).hasClass('.select1'));` even tho the change was on select1. any idea why?

Comment: @Sala, there could be some other issue in your dev environment as the above code example is working as expected:)